# can't access value using .each with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, foreach, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my code:

```
<% @user.errors.each do |key, value| %>
   <% puts 'key is' + key.to_s + 'value is ' + value.to_s %>
   <% if key == 'email' %>
      <% puts 'key is def email' %>
   <% else %>
      <% puts 'key is def not email' %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This outputs:

```
key isemailvalue is can't be blank
key is def not email
key ispassword_confirmationvalue is doesn't match Password
key is def not email
key isprofile_namevalue is This is not valid.
key is def not email
```

The problem is that it is saying "key is def not email" even when they key definitely is "email"  How do I fix this?  Thanks

Comment: Do not use `+` to build string. Do not use `puts` in ERb.Y ou can write it in more readable way by this: `key is <%= key %>, value is <%= value %>`.

Comment: You don't know that key is "email"; you only know that key.to_s returned "email".  When adding debugging to an erb, use `<%=d key %>`.  `d` is a helper function that inspects the value.  That way you'll find out what key _really_ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, there is a difference between Strings and Symbols. Both of these types do not compare as equals (although they often look kind of similar). In your case, the key is probably a Symbol, not a String.

You should thus either compare to a symbol or first "transform" the symbol to a string.

```
key = :email
key == 'email'
# => false

key.to_s == 'email'
# => true

key == :email
# => true
```